# Mysql: Trigger on duplicate key update not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to create a trigger which will trigger on the duplicate key update, however it does not work. The idea is that on each duplicate key update, I want to copy the old content of updated row in the history table.

```
    INSERT INTO t1 
            (
                w1,
                w2
            )
            Select
                w1, 
                w2
            from t2
            on duplicate key update
                w2 = IF(values(w2) is not null and values(w2) != "", VALUES(w2), t1.w2);
```

And the trigger:

```
drop trigger if trigger1;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER trigger1 before update ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO history_table
        (
            w1, -- this is primary key
            w2
        ) 
        values(
            old.w1,
            old.w2
        );


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Does anybody know how to make it work and in general if it is possible.

I tried to make the trigger to start before insert and it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: I suspect the only way to catch this might be an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.  The `BEFORE` trigger that runs would always be `BEFORE INSERT`, and the `BEFORE` trigger should technically fire prior to the server discovering the duplicate key violation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary key on history_table.w1 and you done one update for lets say w1=1, next update for w1=1 will not be recorded because of "Duplicate entry" error

Comment: There is no primary key in the history table and no values are recorded there at all.